# Change color of a div based on the color value from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given the following code, I need to change the color of the "header" div to the color in the corresponding JSON. Using:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
$("#header").css("background-color", $(this).val());
}).change();
```

How can I obtain the hex color in the JSON and apply it to the div?

HTML

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
```

JSON

```
var json = {
"dropdown": [
{
    "optionText": "Budget Starter",
    "headerText": "Work 1-on-1 with your expert to build new spending habits (and break some old ones). Get on a real, sustainable budget that fits your lifestyle.",
    "color": "#59c5c7"
},
{
    "optionText": "5 Year Planner",
    "headerText": "Declare what you want - freedom from debt, security for your family, or an amazing trip. Your expert will build you a custom plan to help you get there.",
    "color": "#009cd0"
},
{
   "optionText": "Portfolio Builder",
    "headerText": "Start training for the world's hardest game: investing. Your expert will help you grow into a disciplined and balanced portfolio manager.",
    "color": "#39ad74"
}
]
};
```

jQuery

```
$('#fetch').click(function() {
$.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify(json)}, function(data) {
    $.each(data.dropdown, function(i, v) {
        $('#dropdown').append('<option value="' + v.optionText + '">' + v.optionText +     
'</option>');
    });
});
});
//change color of header container based on dropdown selection
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
$("#header").css("background-color", $(this).val());
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Um, set the color as the value instead of the text.

```
<option value="' + v.optionText + '">
```

to

```
<option value="' + v.color+ '">
```

If you need the value to be the text, than use a data attribute.

Comment: That worked great! Also trying to figure out why I can't get the JSON to load without the `$("#fetch").click` link. Any ideas?